# Выборка jq и Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, выборка, фильтр

У меня есть таблица, данные там формируются с помощью `ng-repeat`.

Есть фильтры и сортировка. При загрузке страницы у меня срабатывает скрипт, в котором моя выборка в jQ:

```
($('a[name=modal]').click(function(e){var id = $(this).attr('href');})
```

и дальше я в jQ делаю:

```
$(id).fadeIn(1300);
```

чтобы элемент появился.

Данный элемент `(div с $(id))` динамически меняет `id` и содержимое, в таблице, которую формирует *Angular*.

Так вот, при активации любого фильтра всё ещё работает, а при сбросе фильтра jQ отображает только те элементы, которые показывались в выборке при фильтрации.

Если не понятно, могу дополнить. Не понимаю, почему выборка не обновляется и как её принудительно обновить.

Comment: напишите что Вы хотите сделать(простым языком, без кода, что конкретно не получается)? мне кажется что [tag:jQuery] лишний в проекте где используется [tag:angularjs]

Comment: @alexolut У меня есть страница, на ней таблица, она динамическая и используется angular.. данная таблица в будущем будет достаточно большая и я сделал 2 фильтра стандартными средствами angular.

к каждой строчке таблицы мне надо сделать всплывающее окно, в котором будет более подробная информация и доп. действия для пользователя... т.к. данные будут меняться - мне нужно и ссылку с всплывающими окнами тоже менять... так вот jq не видит изменения сделанные с помощью angular...

Comment: Я всего лишь причесал Ваше сообщение к местным стандартам. Ничего не знаю по жюквери :)

Comment: @alexolut, да... я понял) спасибо за это, вы мне помогли.. а то я ещё не привык к этому..)))

Comment: @Bald Привет) На счёт не использования jq с angular я уже читал.. Вопрос описал чуть выше..

Comment: @Makc0809 пока не вижу зачем использовать jQuery, [пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/UMxzIuL9a2yMgSjds9hw?p=preview)

Comment: @Bald Отличный пример, но не могу использовать там bootstrap, т.к. проект достаточно большой и там используется foundation.. при подключении слетают все стили... т.к. там используется подобное.. 

и в angular я вообще пока слаб) он мне конечно нравится... но в то же время не нравится)))

Comment: @Makc0809 Вы можете сами реализовать модальное окно с использованием необходимых вам стилей, но для этого придется познакомиться с ангуляром по ближе(как вариант можно подсмотреть в исходники [`ui.bootstrap.modal`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js))

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не реализовать фильтры и сортировку средствами angular, а не jquery?

Пример:

```js
var filterApp = angular.module( 'filterApp', [] );

filterApp.controller( 'filterController', function ($scope){
 $scope.origins = [
   {name : "Apple", type : "fruit"},
    {name : "Orange", type : "fruit"},
    {name : "Potato", type : "vegetable"}
  ];
  
  $scope.items = $scope.origins;
  
  $scope.filter = function ( itemtype ) {
   var tmp = [];
    
    for( var i = 0; i < $scope.origins.length; i++ ) {
     if( $scope.origins[i].type == itemtype ){
       tmp.push( $scope.origins[i] );
      }
    }
    
    $scope.items = tmp;
  }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="app" ng-app="filterApp">
  <div class="ctrl" ng-controller="filterController">
    <button ng-click="filter('fruit')">Fruit</button>
    <button ng-click="filter('vegetable')">Vegetable</button>
    <div class="item" ng-repeat='item in items'>
      Name: {{item.name}}<br />
      Type: {{item.type}}<br />
      <hr /><br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Выборка и организована с помощью angular... Там вроде все хорошо работает.. Вчера конечно занимался любовью с тем вопросом, но вроде все работает...

Но мне нужно сделать для каждой строчки МОДАЛЬНОЕ ОКНО.. которое я прячу в скрытый див в каждой строчке.. и в каждой строчке я делаю ссылку на этот див...

Answer (score 0):

@bald Спасибо большое за наводку, написал функцию в angular и через ng-click выполняю функцию, куда передаю ID дива, подставляю нужное значение и отображаю нужный мне DIV..

jq тут по сути тогда откидывается, по крайне мере на ближайшее время.. Всем отличного дня! :-)